# C++, template argument error

Tags: c++, templates

Below is my Template matrix which I want to build by taking value from user.
But when I compile it. I am getting below error. Why the error ?

SO_template.cpp: 
In member function `void Matrix<T>::BuildMatrix(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >)':
SO_template.cpp:44: error: expected`;' before "it"

If I specialize my class using int it does not complain why?

```
 template<class T>
  class Matrix
  {
    private:
          vector<T> col;
          int iNumberOfRow;
          int iNumberOfCol;
    public:
     void BuildMatrix(const std::vector<T> stringArray)
     {

         std::vector<T>::iterator it= stringArray.begin();
         cout<<"Build Matrix irow="<<stringArray.size();
         ...
         ...
     }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a "dependent type" - the whole type depends on `T`. Prefix this with `typename` to fix the issue, so make the line read

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator it= stringArray.begin();
```

Comment: To reiterate slightly, this is because the compile doesn't know what std::vector<T>::iterator will refer to, it could for example be a static member variable for some specialisations of vector. So the typename lets the compiler know you expect this to be a type.